# Vim generate function definition from the declaration

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm learning to use vim, but I think it's inconvenient to generate function definition in `.cpp` file from its declaration in `.h` file.

For example, if I declare a function `void print(const vector<int>& arr);` in `A.h`, I have to open `A.cpp` and type the following:

```cpp
void print(const vector<int>& arr) {

}
```

(or use `yy` copy the declaration line, then delete `;` and add `{}`...)
When some derived classes need to override function in base class, it can be a heavy job...

Is there any convenient plugin or command to help me deal with it?

Comment: How do you do it and how is it inconvenient, exactly?

Comment: @romainl sorry,  I added some details just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [lh-cpp plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp) has been providing this feature for quite some time now.

Go on the function declaration, type `:GOTOIMPL` *et voilà!*. It either moves the cursor to a function definition (from its declaration), or if none exists, it generates an empty shell to define that function.

Note: I'm currently in the process of improving the feature to support any kind of function declaration. To support template functions, you'd have to use the [`gotoimpl_with_libclang` branch](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/tree/gotoimpl_with_libclang) and the support plugin [vim-clang](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-clang/tree/V2Upgrade) (in `V2Upgrade` branch).

At this precise moment the sister command `:MOVETOIMPL` doesn't work as expected with constructors defined with initializer-lists, which has side effects on the [`:Constructor`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/gotoimpl_with_libclang/tests/lh/constructor-command.vim)  command. `:MOVETOIMPL` is meant to change an inline definition into a declaration plus a separate definition in a `.cpp`  file typically.

Note: lh-cpp is a complex plugin that provides many things and that has many dependencies. Regarding *overriding*, it provides an `:Override`  command to let us select which function we want to override -- this feature requires my current working branches of lh-cpp and vim-clang.

Comment: `Overiide` is good, but it still has no better way to generate function definition from its declaration?

Comment: It's what `:GOTOIMPL` does.

Comment: Can it detect a source file in which to place the definition?
Is it compatible with `coc-vim`?

Comment: @trozzel, From the header file it'll propose to add it in the .cpp (or equivalent source file -- handled by my alternate-lite plugin). Regarding coc, I guess you are referring to coc.nvim (which I also use simultaneously for other tasks)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Neovim, you can try my plugin: [cppassist.nvim](https://github.com/Kohirus/cppassist.nvim), which can basically be used normally, but there are still many problems. Welcome to ask me questions!

This plugin will recursively search in your working directory until a file matching the same name with the counterpart extension is discovered. Note that the search also respects your `.gitignore` if one exists and any file ignored in `git` will be ignored in the results. As such, I suggest working from the root of your project. Once that file is found, it will automatically be opened in the current buffer. If no corresponding file is found, a message will be logged to the messages buffer -- use `:messages` to review your recent messages.

It uses regular expressions instead of LSP to generate function definition. Currently, it supports most keywords, as well as template types, and can generate multiple function definitions simultaneously in `view` mode.

However, the definition of nested classes is not currently supported. Also, if the function definition is already generated, press the shortcut key again and it will generate the function definition again.

Comment: This answer would be a little more helpful if you could explain how the plugin makes OP's task (copying function definitions from header files) easier. You can "can be used normally"... normally compared to what?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).